# scrollRectToVisible not working in page view controller - iPhone sdks

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiscrollview

I am using Xcode 6.1 and developing for iOS 8.0.

In my application I have a `UIPageViewController`. In that I have added a `UIScrollView`. In the `UIScrollView` I have 4 buttons. When I tap on a button I use this code.

```
long btnValue = sender.tag;
float spaceing = 0;
if(btnValue == 1)
    spaceing = self.scrollView.frame.size.width/4*btnValue;
else
    spaceing = (self.scrollView.frame.size.width/2*btnValue) - self.scrollView.frame.size.width/4;
CGRect frame;
frame.origin.x =  spaceing;
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = NO;
```

This(scrollRectToVisible:) is not working. Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
long btnValue = sender.tag;
float spaceing = 0;
if(btnValue == 1)
    spaceing = self.scrollView.frame.size.width/4*btnValue;
else
    spaceing = (self.scrollView.frame.size.width/2*btnValue) - self.scrollView.frame.size.width/4;
CGRect frame;
frame.origin.x =  spaceing;
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = NO;
```

// Problem is here

```
frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;   //scrollView.frame.size matters
```

set

```
frame.size = self.View.frame.size;
```

and if you are doing it by coding then please add your scrollview into your view

```
[self.view addSubview:yourScrollView];
```